# JTextField equals another JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I have mentioned within the code below what I am looking for:  About 17 rows from the bottom.

```
public void createHotTubs()  
{  
    hotTubs = new JPanel();  
    hotTubs.setLayout(null);  
    labelTubStatus = new JTextArea(6, 30);  
    hotTubs.add(labelTubStatus);  
    JLabel lengthLabel = new JLabel(  
            "Length of hot tub(ft):");  
    lengthLabel.setBounds(10, 15, 260, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(lengthLabel);  
    hotTubLengthText = new JTextField();  
    hotTubLengthText.setBounds(180, 15, 150, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(hotTubLengthText);  
    JLabel widthLabel = new JLabel(  
            "Width of hot tub(ft):");  
    widthLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 260, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(widthLabel);  
    hotTubWidthText = new JTextField();  
    hotTubWidthText.setBounds(180, 40, 150, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(hotTubWidthText);  
    JLabel depthLabel = new JLabel(  
            "Average depth the hot tub(ft):");  
    depthLabel.setBounds(10, 65, 260, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(depthLabel);  
    hotTubDepthText = new JTextField();  
    hotTubDepthText.setBounds(180, 65, 150, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(hotTubDepthText);  
    JLabel volumeLabel = new JLabel("The hot tub volume is:(ft ^3");  
    volumeLabel.setBounds(10, 110, 260, 20);  
    hotTubs.add(volumeLabel);  
    hotTubVolumeText = new JTextField();  
    hotTubVolumeText.setBounds(180, 110, 150, 20);  
    hotTubVolumeText.setEditable(false);  
    hotTubs.add(hotTubVolumeText);  
    final JRadioButton rdbtnRoundTub = new JRadioButton("Round Tub");  
    rdbtnRoundTub.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  
    {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)  
        {  
            hotTubWidthText.setEditable(false);  
        }  
    });  
    rdbtnRoundTub.setSelected(true);  
    rdbtnRoundTub.setBounds(79, 150, 109, 23);  
    hotTubs.add(rdbtnRoundTub);  
    JRadioButton rdbtnOvalTub = new JRadioButton("Oval Tub");  
    rdbtnOvalTub.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  
    {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)  
        {  
            hotTubWidthText.setEditable(true);  
        }  
    });  
    rdbtnOvalTub.setBounds(201, 150, 109, 23);  
    hotTubs.add(rdbtnOvalTub);  
    ButtonGroup radioBtnGroup = new ButtonGroup();  
    radioBtnGroup.add(rdbtnRoundTub);  
    radioBtnGroup.add(rdbtnOvalTub);  
    JButton btnCalculateVlmn = new JButton("Calculate Volume");  
    btnCalculateVlmn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  
    {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)  
        {  
            double width = 0, length = 0, depth = 0, volume = 0;   
            String lengthString, widthString, depthString;   
            lengthString = hotTubLengthText.getText();   
            widthString = hotTubWidthText.getText();   
            depthString = hotTubDepthText.getText();   
            depth = Double.valueOf(depthString); 
            length = Double.valueOf(lengthString); 
            width = Double.valueOf(widthString);

            try 
            {  
                if (rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected())  
                {  
        /* THIS IS WHERE THE WIDTH FIELD NEEDS TO EQUAL THE LENGTH FIELD */ 
                    volume = length * width * depth;  
                }  
                else 
                {  
                    volume = Math.PI * length * width / 4 * depth;  
                }  
                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.###");  
                hotTubVolumeText.setText("" + formatter.format(volume));  
            }  
            catch (NumberFormatException e)  
            {  
                labelTubStatus  
                        .setText("Enter all three numbers!!");  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

[image: After a user enters a number for the length it automatically enters it into the width field.]

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? There are plenty of things you could plausibly mean with the current wording.

Answer (score 0):

If you want compare content:

```
textField1.getText().equals(textField2.getText());
```

for other comparations just look at [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and getValueWhichYouAreInterestedIn()

Answer (score 0):

Judging from you variable names I guess you want to get the width and height out of some user in which case I'd do:

```
double width = Double.parseDouble(textField1.getText());
double height= Double.parseDouble(textField2.getText());

if(width == height){
  Bla bla ...
}
```

Comment: @Jonny:  What I'm doing is that I have two radio buttons, one for pool and one for hot tub.  When the pool is abled, the value entered as the length becomes the width too because it is a circle.

Comment: Then simply do textFieldLength.setText(textFieldWidth.getText());

Comment: @Jonny: I seem to be doing something wrong.  I have copied the code section above of what I'm looking for.  About 17 rows from the bottom.

Comment: I have edited my code to use double because it seems what you need ... and also try using textField1.getText().trim() (to remove trailing spaces) see if it helps

Comment: @Jonny: I added an image above.  Basically after the user enters the length, that value is auto entered into the width field.

Comment: btw try the exclamation   if (**!** rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected())  
                {  
        /* THIS IS WHERE THE WIDTH FIELD NEEDS TO EQUAL THE LENGTH FIELD */ 
                    volume = length * width * depth;  
                }  
                else 
                {  
                    volume = Math.PI * length * width / 4 * depth;  
                }

Comment: I think that there was your problem if (rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected()) 
I think it should be if (**!** rdbtnRoundTub.isSelected())

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have used [Formatted text fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)?  In that case you can do `lengthField.setValue(widthField.getValue())`

But what if the user then enters something in the length box?  Which is the 'master' field?  I would suggest instead disabling the width box, then you don't have to set anything.